# site to listen on port 88

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to get one of my sites to listen on port 88.

In ports.conf in /etc/apache2 on ubuntu server, I add so web app can listen on port 88:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

NameVirtualHost *:88
Listen 88
```

I have this in my etc/apache2/apache2.conf, I have this:

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/
```

Under sites enabled, I have a file looks like this:

```
Listen *:88

NameVirtualHost *:88

<VirtualHost *:88>
  ServerName dogtracking.com
  DocumentRoot /home/doggps/public_html/eaglegps.com/current/public
  <Directory /home/doggps/public_html/eaglegps.com/current/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>

  <LocationMatch "^/assets/.*$">
    Header unset ETag
    FileETag None
    # RFC says only cache for 1 year
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
  </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I try to restart apache:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

And I get:

```
* Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                                                           /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: line 87: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/xtreme/Sites/DogGPS-CMS] does not exist
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
[Thu Oct 18 18:04:21 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:88 has no VirtualHosts
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: line 87: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/xtreme/Sites/DogGPS-CMS] does not exist
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
[Thu Oct 18 18:04:22 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:88 has no VirtualHosts
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
```

Comment: What method did you use to install Apache, and have you modified its init script?  Those permissions errors are interesting.  Aside from that, can you provide the output of `apachectl -S`?

Comment: I don't think `Listen *:88` is valid syntax.  Also, port 88 is kerberos.  Probably not best practice to use reserved ports for websites.  What is your motive behind not using port 80?

Answer (score 1):

You have two `Listen` directives for the same IP address/port combination.  The second one will fail and Apache won't be able to start.

Also, did you use `sudo` to restart Apache?

The permission errors make me think you didn't.